# What is the difference between pointwise confidence interval and uniform confidence interval in econometrics?

Tags: confidence-interval, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I'm reading [Callaway, Bacon, Sant'Anna (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.02637) paper on continuous treatment. In section 6 they show their result of applying their proposed method to [Acemoglu and Finkelstein (2008)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/595014) medicare example. In Figure 5, it shows both the pointwise confidence interval and the uniform confidence interval, however, I never heard of these two names, and i cannot find what is the definition of uniform confidence interval. Do you know what is the difference?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just saw some webpage and realize if i use band as keyword instead of interval, i can find the definition, here is the [wiki explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands) for who might as well trying to figure out

Comment: It would help future visitors to the site if you could give a brief summary of the difference along with the link to the web page.